# Call to undefined method stdClass::toJson()

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, vue.js

Im trying to follow the video of how to apply websockets in laravel in order to have live commenting system but I got this error and I dont know why. I followed every code that he type in his system. Someone has an idea why I got this error?

shownews.blade.php

```
Comment Area
  <h4 class="comments-title" > <span class="fas fa-comment-alt"></span>
                    {{$news->comments()->count()}}
                    Comments</h4>
                  <div class="row" >
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 400px;
                      width: 400px; " id="commentarea" >

                          @foreach($news->comments as $comment)
                            <div class="comment" style="background-color: #f6efef;" >
                          <div class="author-info">
                              <img src={{"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($comment->email))) . "?s=50&d=retro" }} class="author-image" id="image">

                              <div class="author-name">
                                   <h4>{{$comment->name}} </h4>
                                   <p class="author-time"> {{  date('F nS, Y - g:iA' ,strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                            <div class="comment-content">
                                    {{$comment->comment}}
                            </div>
                            </div>
                          @endforeach
                      </div>
                  </div>

Comment Form
       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-4 col-12 form-group">
                          <label for="">Name</label>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="username" required >
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4 col-12 form-group">
                              <label>Email</label>
                           <input type="email" placeholder="Email" v-model="email" required >
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Comment" v-model="commentBox"></textarea>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-submit">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-top:10px" @click.prevent="postComment">Save Comment</button>
                        </div>
                      {{-- </form> --}}

                    </div>
                  </div>

@section('scripts')

<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data:{
            comments:{},
            commentBox = '',
            username = '',
            email = '',
            article:{!! $news->toJson() !!},
        },

        mounted(){
            this.getComments();
        },
        methods:{
            getComments(){
                axios.get(`/api/article/${this.news.id}/comments`)
                    .then((response)=>{
                        this.comments = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            },
            postComment(){
                axios.post(`/api/article/${this.news.id}/comment`,{
                    name: this.username,
                    email: this.email,
                    comment: this.commentBox
                })
                .then((response)=>{
                    this.comments.unshift(response.data);
                    this.commentBox = '';
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

CommentsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comment;
use App\News;
use App\Graph;
use Validator;
use Session;
use Response;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(News $news)
    {
        //
        return response()->json($news->comments());
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, $news_id)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'name'=> 'required | max:255',
            'email'=> 'required| email | max:255',
            'comment'=> 'required | min:5'
        ));

        $news = News::find($news_id);

        $comment = new Comment();

        $comment->name = $request->name;
        $comment->email = $request->email;
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->approved = true;
        $comment->news()->associate($news);

        $comment->save();


        return $comment->toJson();

        // return redirect()->route('article', [$news->id]);
    }

}
```

NewsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\News;
use Validator;
use Image;
use View;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Response;
// use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class NewsController extends Controller
{

//Admin CRUD methods for news here. I diidnt include the code here because its for admin

    public function showNews($id)
    {

        $all = DB::table('news')->get();
        $news = News::find($id);

        return View::make('coin.shownews', compact('news','all'));
    }
}
```

api.php - I followed the video. He uses api routes in order for the data to be passed as json.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('article/{id}','NewsController@showNews');
Route::post('comments/{news_id}', 'CommentsController@store');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
});
```

web.php

```
//comments


//show Individual News with Comments
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']], function(){
    Route::get('/article/{id}', 'NewsController@showNews')->name('article');

});

Route::post('comments/{news_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@store', 'as' => 'comments.store']);
Route::get('comments/{id}/edit',['uses'=>'CommentsController@edit', 'as' => 'comments.edit']);
Route::put('comments/{id}',['uses'=>'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);
Route::delete('comments/{id}',['uses'=>'CommentsController@destroy', 'as' => 'comments.destroy']);
```

Routelist

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                            | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                      |                  | App\Http\Controllers\GraphController@index                        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | adminlogin             | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm           | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | adminlogin             |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                   | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/article/{id}       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@showNews                      | api        |
|        | POST      | api/comments/{news_id} |                  | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@store                     | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | article/{id}           | article          | App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@showNews                      | web        |
|        | PUT       | comments/{id}          | comments.update  | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@update                    | web        |
|        | DELETE    | comments/{id}          | comments.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@destroy                   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | comments/{id}/edit     | comments.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@edit                      | web        |
|        | POST      | comments/{news_id}     | comments.store   | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@store                     | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | logout                 |                  | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@logout                        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | news                   | news.index       | App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@index                         | web        |
|        | POST      | news                   | news.store       | App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@store                         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | news/create            | news.create      | App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@create                        | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | news/{news}            | news.update      | App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@update                        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | news/{news}            | news.show        | App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@show                          | web        |
|        | DELETE    | news/{news}            | news.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@destroy                       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | news/{news}/edit       | news.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@edit                          | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register             | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | roadmap                | roadmap.store    | App\Http\Controllers\RoadmapController@store                      | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | roadmap                | roadmap.index    | App\Http\Controllers\RoadmapController@index                      | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | roadmap/create         | roadmap.create   | App\Http\Controllers\RoadmapController@create                     | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | roadmap/{roadmap}      | roadmap.show     | App\Http\Controllers\RoadmapController@show                       | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | roadmap/{roadmap}      | roadmap.update   | App\Http\Controllers\RoadmapController@update                     | web        |
|        | DELETE    | roadmap/{roadmap}      | roadmap.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\RoadmapController@destroy                    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | roadmap/{roadmap}/edit | roadmap.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\RoadmapController@edit                       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | test                   |                  | App\Http\Controllers\GraphController@test                         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users                  | users.index      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index                         | web        |
|        | POST      | users                  | users.store      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store                         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/create           | users.create     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{user}           | users.show       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show                          | web        |
|        | DELETE    | users/{user}           | users.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy                       | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | users/{user}           | users.update     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update                        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{user}/edit      | users.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit                          | web        |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: You get an error message. When that happens, it tends to include the file and line number where the error occurred. Please show us where the error occurred and only keep the code that's directly relevant to the issue. Right now, you've posted _a lot_ of code without even pointing out _where_ the error happens. Don't make us go through it all and guess where it happens...

Comment: Okay sir sorry about that. I think this code `article:{!! $news->toJson() !!}` gives me the error. Any thoughts about that sir? It is in my blade file. I dont know why I get that error

Comment: can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$comment` variable is `Object type` .There have no `toJson property`. If you want to `return` as `JSON` , use `response`.

```
return  response()->json(['comment' => $comment]);
```

Comment: it still gets me an error sir. But when I remove `article:{!! $news->toJson() !!}` code in my blade file it does not throw an error. But I cant retrive or save the comments

Comment: I need help T_T